# Handling login with a Vaadin Flow webapp, across all layouts globally and across "route" URLs

Tags: session, authentication, vaadin, vaadin-flow

## Vaadin 8

In Vaadin 8, in my `UI` subclass I handled login by examining if a user’s session carried an attribute noting whether they had successfully logged in or not. If not, my `UI` subclass displayed a login layout rather than other content with navigation options such as menu bar and buttons that switch layout within that UI.

## Vaadin 10+

In Vaadin 10 and later, [Vaadin Flow](https://vaadin.com/flow), the [`UI`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/11.0.1/com/vaadin/flow/component/UI.html) class is apparently handled automatically by Vaadin  in a manner transparent to me the app developer. Now the `@Route` and `Router` class approach is suggested as the way to navigate between forms, driven by different URLs attached to each layout. One benefit is the user being able to bookmark a location within the app, in friendly web style.

## Global check

➥ In Vaadin Flow, how does one handle **a global check that the user is logged-in** before displaying any other content?

### Subclass `UI`, as in Vaadin 8

Should I follow the Vaadin 8 approach, writing a subclass of `UI`? If so, how to install my subclass of `UI` in place of the `UI` apparently apparently placed automatically by Vaadin Flow?

Do I follow the example [shown in the manual](https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/migration/3-general-differences.html) with a Servlet definition, and as discussed in [this other Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53271385/642706)?

### `BeforeEnterEvent`

Or should I be doing something with the `BeforeEnterEvent` discussed in [routing lifecycle tutorial](https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/routing/tutorial-routing-lifecycle.html)? While the top of that page has a brief mention of listeners firing on the `UI` instance, the examples across the rest of the page involve code on the layout rather than `UI`. So I do not understand how to handle global check across all my current and future layouts defined in my app.

---

My question has nothing to do with storing passwords, credentials, hash & salt, etc. I am asking about a way to gracefully check for login being completed to block/grant access to the content of a Vaadin web app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of different alternatives that might be useful for you, slightly depending on how you've structured you application.

1. Make your main layout class implement `BeforeEnterObserver`. This is a really simple approach as long as you only have one main layout for the entire application. One drawback is that there would be no checks for any `@Route` class that you don't configure to directly or indirectly use your main layout.
2. Implement `RouterLayout.showRouterLayoutContent` in your main layout (instead of relying on the default implementation), and do the checks there. This again only works when the main layout is actually used for all views, but might be challenging if having intermediate layouts in between.
3. Define your own `AbstractView` class that does access control on its own for each instance. This again requires that you remember to always use `AbstractView` for all your routes.
4. Register a UI-wide `BeforeEnterListener` that performs access checks. This is a little more complex to set up since you'd need a `VaadinServiceInitListener` that adds a `UIInitListener` that adds the actual listener. (Setting up those listeners is described in the manual [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/advanced/tutorial-service-init-listener.html) and [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/advanced/tutorial-ui-init-listener.html).) On the other hand, this approach is able to intercept any navigation event regardless of layout nesting and without requiring a special view class.

Comment: I cannot find an `AbstractView` interface or abstract class (from # 3 above) [in the JavaDoc](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/12.0.0.alpha5/com/vaadin/flow/component/Component.html)

Comment: My intention was that you'd create your own `AbstractView` class specifically for your application. I made a small edit to my answer to hopefully make that a little bit clearer.

Comment: how to implement the 4th alternative: https://github.com/vaadin/flow-and-components-documentation/blob/master/documentation/advanced/tutorial-service-init-listener.asciidoc
Demo project: https://github.com/vaadin/bookstore-starter-flow/

Comment: @enkara Doing anything `UI`-based in impractical now in Vaadin 14 as the `UI` instance is rapidly replaced, sometimes within seconds, one after another without end.

Comment: @BasilBourque is there a ticket about UI instances being more frequently replaced in V14 compared to previous versions? I'm only aware of https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/6321, which shouldn't (according to my understanding) have any impact in this particular case.

Comment: I do not know about more or less frequently than versions 10 to 13. All I know is that in several hours of experimenting with `@PWA` on or off, `@PreserveOnRefresh` on or off, Jetty 9 or 10, and Vaadin 14.0.1/2/3/4/5 versus 14.1.0.alpha1/2, I have been unable to find any configuration where the UI object is stable (meaning one instance per session).

Comment: Sure, but have you observed anything that wouldn't be covered by https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/6321#issuecomment-527957755? If those are all the cases that happen to you, then it's just about spurious 404 views and shouldn't really have any impact on access control?