# Setting content of my `UI` subclass in Vaadin Flow web app

Tags: java, user-interface, vaadin, vaadin-flow

In Vaadin Flow, writing a subclass of `UI` class is no longer necessary. Yet the page of the manual on [*Differences Between V10 and V8 Applications*](https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/migration/3-general-differences.html) suggests we are free to do so.

The problem: The [`UI`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/11.0.1/com/vaadin/flow/component/UI.html) class in Flow has no `UI::setContent` method.

This usual line of code in our `UI::init` method fails in Flow:

```
this.setContent( layout );  // <--- No method `setContent` found in Flow
```

➥ How do we set the content to be displayed within our `UI` subclass at runtime?

Here is my code, with the line of `setContent` that fails.

```
package com.acme;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.UI;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServletConfiguration;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

public class MyUI extends UI {
    protected void init ( VaadinRequest request ) {
        VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        this.setContent( layout );
    }

    @WebServlet (
        urlPatterns = "/*",
        name = "myservlet",
        asyncSupported = true
    )
    // The UI configuration is optional
    @VaadinServletConfiguration (
        ui = MyUI.class,
        productionMode = false
    )
    public class MyServlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }
}
```

Comment: On a related note: [*Handling login with a Vaadin Flow webapp, across all layouts globally and across “route” URLs*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53254167/642706)

Answer (score 1):

The `UI` is a component itself and implements `HasComponents`. Hence, you can simply call `add(Component...)` method to fill it with components.